# c# .net framework web api controller error 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am an noob in .net framework web api c# so my question is when i try to recieve webhook data the web hook test function that sends data gives a 404 error. I try to call the webhook reciever controller with ...:3001/api/USIAccountWebhook. I can call ...:3001/api/Values with no problem at all.

Beginning of the controller code where i think I'm going wrong:

> > 

```
public class USIAccountWebhookController : ApiController
{

    [System.Web.Http.Route("webhooks/accountupdated")]
    public async Task<GenericResponseDTO> AccountUpdatedAsync(AccountDTO value)
    {
        string EPrelationID;
        //SecretKey from the notification should always be checked for security.
        if (value.SecretKey != SecretKey)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
```

<<
Does anyone maybe have an idea or tips?
Thanks!

Best regards,
Jeroen

Comment: Try changing your route to [System.Web.Http.Route("api/USIAccountWebhook/AccountUpdatedAsync/")]

Answer (score 0):

404 is a very common error that says you taht the URI you're calling did't exist, the Controller code you shared informs us that the **correct route** for the method you're trying to call is:

```
...:3001/api/webhooks/accountupdated
```

as stated here:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("webhooks/accountupdated")]
```

Just to bne sure, also search for something like:

```
 [RoutePrefix("some_url_chunks_more")]
```

(you need to call the method, not the class)